# Cannot convert value of type to required type [org.springframework.aop.Pointcut]

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, aop, spring-aop

I am trying to setup Spring transaction management for Hibernate however, I meet the following issue...

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [ac.nz.unitec.service.impl.UserServiceImpl] to required type [org.springframework.aop.Pointcut] for property 'pointcut': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Here are more details and the Spring configuration

There is an interface called UserService and UserServiceImpl implements the interface.

Spring Configuration:

```
<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="userService"
        expression="execution(public * ac.nz.unitec.service.UserService.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userService" />
</aop:config>
             <!--I also tried the following one but didn't work out either-->
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="userService"
        expression="execution(public * ac.nz.unitec.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userService" />
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="exist" />
        <tx:method name="add" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<!--Not sure whether the following piece matters as it has duplicate name with the one in aop config-->

<bean name="userService" class="ac.nz.unitec.service.impl.UserServiceImpl">
    <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
</bean>
```

Updated Spring Configuration xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName"
        value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>ac/nz/unitec/model/User.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="userServiceOperation"
        expression="execution(* ac.nz.unitec.service.UserService.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="userServiceOperation" />
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="exist" />
        <tx:method name="add" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<bean name="userAction" class="ac.nz.unitec.action.UserAction" scope="prototype">
    <property name="userService" ref="userService"/>
</bean>

<bean name="retrieveAction" class="ac.nz.unitec.action.RetrieveAction" scope="prototype">
    <property name="userService" ref="userService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userService" class="ac.nz.unitec.service.impl.UserServiceImpl">
    <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
</bean>

<bean name="userDao" class="ac.nz.unitec.dao.impl.UserDaoImpl">
    <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate"/>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Really appreciated for any suggestions, thanks ahead

Comment: Where is your aspect code? Please update the question.

Comment: @kriegaex The aspect code is not needed

Comment: Listen, you are asking an AspectJ expert about an AspectJ problem. If you think you know better what I need in order to answer your question, why are you asking anyway? Answer your own question then. Besides, you wrote an answer to your own question - but it is incomprehensible, really. This way neither the question nor the answer are useful to anyone else reading this page. Maybe you better delete the whole question altogether.

Comment: @kriegaex Hi I am sorry if my reply offended you, I didn't intend to. I upload the whole spring configuration xml. In the old one, in <aop:config>, the <aop:pointcut> id is userService. However, there is a bean whose name is also userService. I changed the <aop:pointcut> id to userServiceOperation and it worked. So I think userService shown both in <aop:pointcut> and <bean> configs resulted in the issue I met. I apologize for such a rude reply.

Comment: Don't worry, your reply was not rude and your problem was really unrelated to the actual aspect code, but this is pure chance. The problem could have been in an aspect and if you ask questions here it is always a good idea to ask smartly, i.e. in a way which enables others to reproduce your problem. By just reading your config file people who want to help you might just overlook something. Usually you should provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

In the old config file, in aop:config, the aop:pointcut id is userService. However, there is a bean whose name is also userService. I changed the aop:pointcut id to userServiceOperation and it fixed the issue